# Linearly Regressing Pooled Data

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to regress some simple pooled data. My data has 60 observations and three columns: Weight, Height, and Sex (female=1, male=0).

If I regress thus, Weight ~ Height + Sex, my model is fairly satisfactory, but the residuals are not homoscedastic (green errors are male, blue female):

[image: plot]

I tried regressing on the log of Weight and/or Height, but that didn't do much. What should I do to make the residuals homescedastic and/or make my model more accurate? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Doing a generalized regression model gives the following.

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: Weight ~ h + s 
  Data: P149 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  514.2221 524.4374 -252.1111

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Sex 
 Parameter estimates:
        0         1 
1.0000000 0.6685307 

Coefficients:
                 Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  27.197499  51.88129  0.524226  0.6022
h             1.852382   0.75634  2.449128  0.0174
s           -25.284478   5.53300 -4.569755  0.0000

 Correlation: 
  (Intr) h     
h -0.997       
s -0.524  0.466

Standardized residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.6655243 -0.6879858 -0.1839396  0.5628971  3.9857544 

Residual standard error: 22.13369 
Degrees of freedom: 60 total; 57 residual
```

With this s. residual plot:

[image]

Could someone please explain how precisely this model is different from a standard multiple regression model? Thanks.

Comment: You should really consider adding an interaction term to the model.  I would expect the relationship between height and weight to be different between the sexes. So, you should at least test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a model framework that allows you to model the different variation in males and females. Package nlme provides a generalized least squares implementation (`gls`) that can be used in conjunction with the `varIdent` function to specify the appropriate variance structure. E.g.,  you could try something like

```
library(nlme)
gls(Weight ~ Height + Sex, weights=varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Sex), data=dat)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the R output. Is gls correcting the variance or just telling me the structure?

`Generalized least squares...
  Model: Weight ~ Height + Sex 
  
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  514.2221 524.4374 -252.1111

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Sex 
 Parameter estimates:
        0         1 
1.0000000 0.6685307 

Coefficients:
                 Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  27.197499  51.88129  0.524226  0.6022
Height        1.852382   0.75634  2.449128  0.0174
Sex         -25.284478   5.53300 -4.569755  0.0000`

Comment: It is including the different variance in the model. The output (which is difficult to read in a comment) tells you that the residual variance of sex 1 is 0.669 times the residual variance of sex 0. The value of 0.669 is fitted.